# What is the easiest way to copy files with filename substitution?

Tags: unix, substitution

What is the easiest way to copy files with filename substitution ?
For Eg. How to copy file1.txt, file1.rpt as file2.txt, file2.rpt ?

Comment: You'll need to tag with the programming language you're asking about.  In any case, this is much too broad for SO - you should show your effort so far, and explain why it's inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp file{1,2}.txt

cp file{1,2}.rpt
```